# Passing custom apex class to aura attribute

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have an apex class like this:

```
public class AccountController {
    public class MeterInput {
        @AuraEnabled public String ME_Name { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled public String ME_Meter_ID { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled public Decimal ME_GPS_Location_Latitude_s { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled public Decimal GU_GPS_Location_Longitude_s { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to call it under lightning component, but it doesn't work.
My tries:
component:

```
<aura:component controller="AccountController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute type = "AccountController.MeterInput" name ="meterInput" />
...
</aura:component>
...
   <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="meterName" label="Name"
                                             name="meterName"
                                             value = {!v.response.NameStromerzeugungseinheit}"
                                             required="true"
    />
```

controller:

```
var meterInput = component.get("v.meterInput");
meterInput.ME_Name = component.find("meterName").get("v.value")
```

I queried meterName from an API Call. As shown in the code
Error I got : This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:PlantForm$controller$CreatePlant [Cannot set property 'ME_Name' of null] Failing descriptor: {c:PlantForm$controller$CreatePlant}
Any suggestion?

Comment: why you need like this? you can create the attribute of type object and get the data from apex.

Comment: @Amol I have a lightning:input form and I need to map the inputs to different objects. What do you mean "get the data from apex"?

Comment: I didn't get your point, but you can use wrapper class in component refer this [link](https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/06/use-wrapper-class-lightning-component/)

Comment: We're missing a lot of relevant code, can you add how you retrieve the data and how it's placed into the `meterName` attribute? Also, adding the definition of `meterName` might be useful.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I have updated the code. Basically it's a lightning:input component and the user need to enter it

Comment: and the error message? I still can't understand what the problem is either

Comment: @SebastianKessel : I got this error - This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:PlantForm$controller$CreatePlant [Cannot set property 'ME_Name' of null] Failing descriptor: {c:PlantForm$controller$CreatePlant}

Comment: Your attribute is pointing to a class but needs an instance, which you're not providing to it. Give it a default value either on the attribute or on init.

Answer (score 1):

in our app also some scenario's custom Apex is not working in lightning component as `aura:attribute` still we r researching on that, but for now we came up with below work around. you need to use `Map` instated of `custom Apex class`

```
<aura:component controller="AccountController"implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
   <aura:attribute type = "Map" default="{}" name ="meterInput" />
   <lightning:input label="ME Name" value="{!v.meterInput.ME_Name }" />
   <lightning:button variant="destructive" label="call apex" title="Brand action" onclick="{!c.servercall}" />
```

**cmpcontroller.js**

```
servercall: function(component, event, helper){
   var inputobj = component.get("v.meterInput");
    var action = component.get("c.serverApexcall");
        action.setParams({"apexinputobj" : inputobj });
  //server action send inputobj parameter to Apex method. 
}
```

**Apexcontroller**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void serverApexcall(MeterInput  apexinputobj){
 system.debug('me name from input : '+ apexinputobj.ME_Name)
}
```